# I can not install sw_urdf_exporter

Tags: ros, sw-urdf-exporter, solidworks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to install sw_urdf_exporter a few days ago and I can not seem to get an error compiling the SW2URDF code. I do not know if my error is because I'm using visual studio (I use the visual code with compilers in C #) and the error that appears when compiling is "Could not start debugging because debug target 'c: \ programfiles \ SOLIDWORKS Corp \ SOLIDWORKS (2) \ SLDWORKS.exe is missing. Build the project and try again, or set the properties to a correct destination assembly location. "

my solidworks version is 2016, would it be something like this?

please detail me better how to install it

---

Edit: so my solid is the same 2016, in the installation tutorial asks me to install SW2URDFsetup and in that I installed everything right, but asks me to download the visual c # express 2010 and compile the bitbucket code and when compiling this software it of the error, I do not know where I am wrong and arriving in part 2.2 of the tutorial appears the error quoted above

my doubt is there, only using the installer can I export to urdf? the part of the code is not part of the installation? Only the installer solves my problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270071/i-can-not-install-sw_urdf_exporter/) by [Juunio](https://answers.ros.org/users/31764/juunio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-02**:
This is a duplicate of #q270070, but there your solidworks version is `2017`. Please check that and delete one these posts.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-02**:
Also: please tell us why you can't use the provided installer. Unless you want to *work on* the code of the exporter itself, you don't need to compile anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need to compile the source code, if you don't intend to modify the code itself. Since the installer worked just fine, you should now be able to see the 'Export to URDF' option in the file menu when you open your SolidWorks part or Assembly.

---

Originally posted by [brawner](https://answers.ros.org/users/2146/brawner/) with karma: 581 on 2017-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juunio](https://answers.ros.org/users/31764/juunio/) on 2017-09-04**:
does not appear to me, you talk in the file tab that descends the options save, save as and everything else, right? I saw in videos that appears so and have in the file add-ons that also appears, it's all correct in the supplements, can it be anything?